# ofRegisterEvent method

Tags: android, methods, gps, openframeworks

could someone please explain me the meaning of this `*ofRegisterEvent*' method:

```
#ifdef TARGET_ANDROID
 gpsStatus = 1;
 gpsCtrl.startGPS();
 ofRegisterGPSEvent(this);
#endif
```

I'm not completely able to figure out why I have to use that.

Thanks

Comment: Meanwhile, I found an interesting reading that explained me something at [this link](https://books.google.dk/books?id=sAsHA1HM1WcC&pg=PA695&lpg=PA695&dq=%22ofRegisterGPSEvent%22&source=bl&ots=KGB2Td6yla&sig=6IQ8gIPS0Hd_3ZUBHd-0nWMOwtI&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22ofRegisterGPSEvent%22&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

I'd research event handlers if I were you. It will also likely utilise this class:
http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/events/ofEvent.html

It's hard to say without seeing more but it appears to be adding a passing in details about the current class into what could be a listener.